# Query data from MySQL into Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Search for many related cases and I appreciate I learned just reading helpful comments in those problems, but this one is just a dead end for me.

Background: I'm working on a remote DB (oracle) that I don't have rights to, where all my data came from and putting in in my local db(mysql-phpmyadmin) for local usage. 
I have a phpmyadmin database with a table named: rli_tbl and these are the columns:

```
 - DATA CENTER
 - MASTER RLI 
 - RLI
```

And I have an oracle query :

```
select ci.catalog_item_name,lnop.value as os_type from 
ln_options_at_readytosignoff lnop, reservationlineitems rli, order_item oi,        catalog_item ci
where lnop.quote_ln_id=rli.quote_ln_id
and rli.reservation_ln_id in(select a.reservation_ln_id from reservationlineitems a
left join reservationlineitems b on a.reservation_ln_id = b.depends_on
where (a.reservation_ln_id =279277 or b.reservation_ln_id=279277));
```

Now the problem here is i need to specify an RLI in the last line.

```
where (a.reservation_ln_id =123456 or b.reservation_ln_id=654321));
```

However RLI is composed of 12 digit hyphenated number example: 123456-654321

Now here's what Im trying to figure out:

1st : Query and slice RLI data into two parts 1st 6 digits and last 6 digits from local db.

2nd : Put the 1st 6 digits and last 6 digits respectively in the oracle query(is this even possible?)

```
where (a.reservation_ln_id =123456 or b.reservation_ln_id=654321));
```

Any insight, suggestion, comments could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
where 
(a.reservation_ln_id || '-' || b.reservation_ln_id = '123456-654321')
```

Comment: Care to fix your syntax?